# Using variables in JSF code

Tags: jsp, jsf, jstl

I am strugeling with with getting the parameters playerName and clubName send to the forEach loop. They are correctly send with the commandButton so I am sure there are values in them. But it seems like they are not evaluated in time for the forEach??? As you can see the variables are not saved in a bean.

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Spelare"></h:outputText>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="playerMenu" value="#{playerName}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{serviceHCP.allPlayers}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputText value="Klubb"></h:outputText>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="ClubMenu" value="#{clubName}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{serviceHCP.clubs}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

    </h:panelGrid>
    Players
    <c:forEach var="list" items="#{serviceSeries.getSeriesForPlayer(clubName, playerName)}">

<--- More code --->
    </c:forEach>
    <h:commandButton value="Spara" action="#{serviceHCP.saveSerieTotal(clubName, playerName, serieName, noSeries, serie) }"></h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Huh? Where did you learn writing JSF this strange and ineffective way? Just make them normal bean properties. Don't tight-couple the job of the model and controller into the view. Don't perform business logic in getter methods.

Comment: Can't really see any inefficiencies in this way of doing it. As you can see I am passing the variables to different areas om the app. Creating a new class for passing variables seems very inefficient  to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the method to be invoked once or twice due to the [JSF lifecycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-intro006.htm#GLPRC):

[image]

*The JSTL tags are not components so they don't get involved with every phase.*

Consider this view snippet:

```
<c:forEach var="_foo" items="#{bar.list(baz)}" />
<h:form>
  <h:inputText value="#{baz}" />
  <h:commandButton value="foo" />
</h:form>
```

Bound to this bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bar {
  public List<String> list(String baz) {
    PhaseId phase = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getCurrentPhaseId();
    System.out.println(phase + " " + baz);
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
}
```

The list method prints out the current lifecycle phase and its argument when invoked. When I enter a value and submit the form this is printed in the server log:

```
INFO:   RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO:   RENDER_RESPONSE 6 hello
```

The JSF servlet receives the field value as a parameter. It won't pushed into the model (here, the request scope) until the *Update Model Values* phase. If something causes the lifecycle to shortcut to *Render Response* (like a validation failure) then this will not happen at all.

**TL;DR**

Be aware of when and how often expressions are evaluated.